# Mostrar ordenados alfabéticamente los objetos en el admin de Django

Tags: python, django, ordenamiento

En mi proyecto de Django he creado una app llamada `Deportes` (agregada en el `settings.py`). Al entrar en el administrador de Django en la zona de Deportes se muestran listados los deportes agregados. Esta lista me gustaría que se mostrase ordenada alfabéticamente.

El código que uso dentro de `models.py` es sencillísimo:

```
def __unicode__(self): 
    return self.nombre_deporte_es
```

Comment: Posible solución: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11999945/554319

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Una opción es, si quisieras que el orden aplique a nivel del sitema y para todos los casos, tienes que definir este orden en el [`Meta`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#model-meta-options) de tu modelo, específicamente la opción [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#ordering):

```
# models.py

class Deportes(models.Model):
    # Tus columnas

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.nombre_deporte_es

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['nombre_deporte_es']
```

La forma anterior aplicaría para orden por nombre ascendente. Para orden descendente puedes usar:

```
# models.py

class Deportes(models.Model):
    # Tus columnas

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.nombre_deporte_es

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-nombre_deporte_es'] # Nota el guión
```

De no ser el caso que quieras que este orden aplica a nivel de todo el sistema y solo quieres que aplique para tu admin, tendrías que hacer algunos cambios en tu `admin.py` y editar la función [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset):

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from tuapp.models import Deportes

class DeportesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = Deportes.objects.all().order_by('nombre_deporte_es')
        return queryset


admin.site.register(Deportes, DeportesAdmin)
```